# How Can I Sum up multiple columns and put the result into another existing column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my table:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceTable] (
        [Id]                 INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [CodeColumn]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [NameColumn]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
        [QTYColumn]          INT           NULL,
        [TotalQTYColumn]     INT           NULL,
        [UnitCostColumn]     INT           NOT NULL,
        [TotalCost]          INT           NULL,
        [DiscountRateColumn] FLOAT (53)    DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    );
```

I want something like this:

```
SELECT 
CodeColumn,
NameColumn
TotalQTYColumn = SUM(QTYColumn   
TotalCost = SUM(UnitCostColumn)*SUM(QTYColumn))
blah
FROM InvoiceTable
```

This doesnt solve my problem:

```
select
blah
    SUM(UnitCostColumn)*SUM(QTYColumn) AS TotalCost
    SUM(QTYColumn) AS TotalQTYColumn, 
blah
```

cause I want to add the resualt to an existing column in my table not something new...

this didnt work for me:

```
SELECT
CodeColumn,
NameColumn,
(select TotalQTYColumn = SUM(QTYColumn))
UnitCostColumn,
DiscountRateColumn,
(select TotalCost = SUM(UnitCostColumn)*SUM(QTYColumn))
FROM InvoiceTable
GROUP BY CodeColumn, NameColumn, UnitCostColumn, DiscountRateColumn
```

I dont know why it doesnt show the results in TotalCost Column and TotalQTY column when I want to see the results on a datagridview.

Comment: The second query is not clear. can you review it again?

Comment: @ThilinaNakkawita Its just a select statement in SQL: `select X from Xtable`. which I wrote just the `select X` part. those blahs mean something anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking at your query and thinking that the arithmetic is not what you want.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT CodeColumn, NameColumn
       TotalQTYColumn = SUM(QTYColumn)  
       TotalCost = SUM(UnitCostColumn * QTYColumn)
FROM InvoiceTable
```

Comment: Yes It did. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Sum of the entire column and not a specific result set you mus leave the group by out and make use of a sub query such as

```
SELECT (select sum(QTYColumn) FROM InvoiceTable) as 'TotalQTYColumn',NameColumn, CodeColumn FROM InvoiceTable;
```

that should lead you on the right path

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
SELECT
CodeColumn,
NameColumn,
SUM(QTYColumn) as TotalQTYColumn
UnitCostColumn,
DiscountRateColumn,
SUM(UnitCostColumn)*SUM(QTYColumn) as TotalCost
FROM InvoiceTable
GROUP BY CodeColumn, NameColumn, UnitCostColumn, DiscountRateColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing the right thing. You try to `UPDATE` the value of the column inside a `SELECT` statement. You should do

```
update table InvoiceTable (TotalQTYColumn, TotalCost)
values(sum(QTYColumn), sum(UnitCostColumn) * sum(QTYColumn))
where Id = @id
```

And do this inside a loop where you define the `@id`.
And then you can just make a `SELECT` statement to retreive the value.

But I think you have an issue in the logic of your table.

Why do you have 2 columns that contains the total quantity of columns in the same table? You have a lot of replication inside your table with thoses 2 columns and more of that you need to update thoses values every single time you insert a new value inside your table...

You should erase `[TotalQTYColumn]` and `[TotalCost]` from your table because there are dynamic values and do

```
    SELECT 
    CodeColumn,
    NameColumn
    SUM(UnitCostColumn)*SUM(QTYColumn) AS TotalCost
    SUM(QTYColumn) AS TotalQTYColumn
    FROM InvoiceTable
```

You want to add the result of the `SUM` to an existing column but in your case you are trying to `UPDATE` the value of the columns in the `SELECT` statement and that's wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did help me actually. But I have some questions. first I want to answer that I have TOTALQTY and QTYColumn because I have some kind of an invoice program. When the user inserts the same comodity with a new QTY the new QTY goes to QTYColumn and the total is calculated in TOTALQTYCOLUMN. thats why im using group by clause...

Comment: My first Question is How to do that inside a loop? second Question: when Im using  sum(blah) as `total QTY`, the total cost column is not an actual column... So im not able to recall that column in another store procedure. for example Im not able to say `set total QTY = Total QTY + 1` in another store procedure. that was my problem so I chose to have totalQTY in an actual column

Comment: I understand the need of the `QTYColumn`, but I don't understand the need to have the `TotalQTY` in your record... because it's a value that will be replicated in each row where `CodeColumn, NameColumn,UnitCostColumn and DiscountRateColumn` are the same, so each time you made an insert/update/delete you need to update your entire table because all your row are related otherwise your table is not updated... And if you want to increment the value inside another stored procedure you just need to do `set TotalQTY = SUM(QTYColumn) +1`

Comment: Yes I got it youre so right. BUT my problem still exists with in this way. when I say `sum(blah) as TotalQTYColumn`, Im not able to recall the `TotalQTYColumn` in another storeprocedure. system underlines it with a red line which means this column is not detected or it does not exist. what can I do with this? You actually added to my knowledge thank you. thank you for your time.

Comment: If `TotalQTYColumn` is in your `SELECT` that is in your return statement from your first stored procedure I don't understand why it does not exist, maybe it's because it's not a column from your table it doesn't understand that it's a dynamic built column but it will compile, you can still run without having an error normally